# sequence of photos are mixed in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, sdwebimage

I have a dynamic array of photos. When I'm trying to put this in horizontal UIScrollView, I'm losing the sequence of photos. UIScrollView is in UITableViewCell. the code is running below function

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 for (int i = 0; i <  [self.attachments count]; i++)
{        [newArr setDictionary:[self.attachments objectAtIndex:i]];

    if ([[newArr objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"video"]) {

        [typeVideo setDictionary:[newArr objectForKey:@"video"]];
        self.photoID         = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [typePhoto objectForKey:@"id"]];

        self.urlPhotoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [typeVideo objectForKey:@"photo_75"]];

    } else  {

        [typePhoto setDictionary:[newArr objectForKey:@"photo"]];
        self.urlPhotoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [typePhoto objectForKey:@"photo_75"]];
        self.photoID         = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [typePhoto objectForKey:@"id"]];

    }

 //   self.imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollWidth,0,50,40)];

// Get image from URL  this code works cool but frozen
  //  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlPhotoString];
//        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
//        self.img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    self.btn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollWidth,0,50,40)];

    [SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlPhotoString]
                                                        options:0
                                                       progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
     {
         NSLog(@"donwloading...");
     }
                                                      completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished)
     {
         if (image && finished)
         {
             self.img = image;

         }
     }];

    scrollWidth=scrollWidth+80;

//        self.imageView.image= self.img;
//        self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//        self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:self.photoID];

    [self.btn setTag: [myNumber longLongValue]];

    NSString* postID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%d", [[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"], i];

    self.btn.titleLabel.text = postID;
    self.btn.titleLabel.hidden=YES;

    [self.btn  setBackgroundImage:self.img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.gallery  addSubview: self.btn];

    [self.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextPhoto:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

[self.gallery  setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, 30)];

[postCell.contentView addSubview:  self.gallery];
```

When I'm trying to get photos synchronously, I'm getting What I need, but It's frozen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I truly recommend using UICollectionView for horizontally scrolling views. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html

Comment: I know  in this case i must  use UICollectionView but i have problem with UICollection. I'm beginner. I can't understand how to work with UICollection inside TableViewCell

Comment: If you have lots of images this will be a nightmare for memory. CollectionView behaves much similar to TableViews. The fastest way to use UICollectionView http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: ty. I have problem with UICollectionView. How to change numberOfItemsInSection dynamically ?For example self.attachments.count but i get attachments in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
When i build this code i have static itemsInSection.
return [self.attachments count];

Comment: Let me get this straight; you're having an array of arrays?

Comment: This must look like this http://postimg.org/image/7u8fl141j/ (screen my app). images count mutable.  Full code is here http://codepaste.net/ag4gs5